# Is there a way to fill the area between two circles?

Tags: mesh, faces

There's a way to fill with faces only the area between the larger circle and the the smaller one?
I mean.. It's a wheel and I'm trying to fill the rubber part of it.

Using the fill function <kbd>F</kbd> it *fills* everything inside the bigger circle.

[image: wheel]

Comment: I don't think is possible to create an unique n-gon capable of filling those boundaries. You should at least make two regions. Would this in your case be suitable or you are looking for a one-face solution?

Comment: oh.. you are right, It works well this way!

Comment: I was searching for a one-face solution but it is not necessary :)

Comment: Here's a link to the [Blender for dummies 3rd edition book's page](https://books.google.it/books?id=fO_GBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA83&dq=blender%20ngon%20limitations&hl=it&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q=blender%20ngon%20limitations&f=false) about n-gon limitations where it is said that such feature "is not currently supported" referring to the 2015 versions of Blender.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If both circles have the same number of vertices you can use the *Bridge Edge Loops* (from the menu *Mesh > Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*, or press <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the search menu, and start typing *bridge edge loops*)

[image]

It will not fill as an NGon, that is generally not desirable anyway, instead creating an even quad-based topology.

[image]

Comment: Thank u Duarte!! It is a cool solution to the problem!! :)

Comment: Most welcome, hope it helped.

Answer (score 6):

Also, another way to do this, would be to add in a circle, hit `F` to fill it. Then hit `I` to inset the circle to a desired size, then simply delete the inner circle.

Comment: Very valid solution!!
 Thank You for sharing it!! :)