# How would I be able to fill in the gap indicated by the arrow without filling in the middle portion?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

Hello,

I am trying to fill the edge gap of this skull indicated by the red arrows to the right however, when i press F, it covers the whole area including the middle portion which i want to be hollow inside. Is there a way to only fill in the wanted gap? I appreciate the help

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to fill the area between two circles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles)

Comment: I tried to bridge the gaps but it ends up filling the whole top area

Comment: maybe try in several steps?

Comment: Does it needs to be "filled" and connected? I´ll use a boolean and cut it with a plane, leave then another plane to "cap" that region.

Comment: Since the mesh has already horrible geometry, I'd give @PierreSchiller's Idea a try.