# Make a face from a mesh with a hole

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, bezier-curves, faces

How can I create a face for extrusion with a hole inside in edit mode? In my case I want to extrude only the "C" from a mesh marked in blue and not the filled innside part.

[image: screenshot c inside]

Comment: do you need to keep the external border (the rectangular mesh around your C)?

Comment: this part of the mesh is for another similar operation

Comment: so if what you show is a curve you need to convert to a mesh (well if you want it to be a mesh and if it's not already), then you need to fill with faces, then extrude... what are the difficulties you've met? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I want to fill only the blue "c" with faces, not the rest of them

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles/46351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you basic mesh looks like, so it's hard to tell what you're supposed to do, I guess you can create edges between the existing vertices but I recomposed your shape with several successive extrusions along the  letter profile. To make an angle round I've selected an edge and use the bevel tool (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>). When you have finished with the flat mesh, select all and extrude up (<kbd>E</kbd>). Is it what you want?

Edit: And oh yes, as Duarte explains, if you have the same amount of vertices on the internal and external edges, you can simply select them and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*. If they don't have the same amount, create enough vertices to make the count equal. You can play with the bridge parameters on the bottom of the Tools panel, on the left of the 3D View.

[image]