# How do I create a hollow cylinder?

Tags: edit-mode

My original post has become too confusing.  I'll start over.

---

How do I create a hollow cylinder?  I am using Blender 3.0.

---

---

Response to Allen Simpson Answer:  It works, but ........

Initial sequence => Add > Mesh > Cylinder > F9 > Cap Fill Type menu appears > Cap Fill Type: Nothing => results in a hollow cylinder.

--- Case 1:
Wrench icon (right side) > Add Modified > Solidify > Thickness > Changes the cylinder wall thickness.

This works!

--- Case 2:
Scene Properties (triangle icon) > Units: Imperial - Length: Inches ... N > Dimensions: 0.5, 0.5, 1 ... Wrench icon (right side) > Add Modified > Solidify > Thickness: starts at 0.393701 in => cylinder wall is very thin

Changing thickness makes the wall thicker, but is inaccurate for a 0.5 in diameter cylinder.  Setting thickness to 20 inches fills about half of the (outside dimension 0.5 inch diameter) cylinder hole

[image]

Comment: Since your question is asking for clarifications on another Q&A, you can try and add a comment for further information on the answers instead of a new question. The users are both still active on this site so I'm sure you'll get your information rapidly. Cheers

Comment: To create a circle press Shift A > Mesh > Circle, then press Tab to go in Edit mode, select all and press E to extrude inwards. Note that the shortcuts have changed for the Knife tool, to activate it's now K, but A to cut orthogonally

Comment: If you're struggling on how to create a circle mesh then start by watching beginner introductory tutorials on Youtube, those are quite basic questions. This answers https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150547/1245 outlines the procedure quite well. There isn't any "tag" for new user questions nor could it be added. Tags are for questions in general, not users asking them

Comment: You can use arithmetic operation (e.g. subtraction) with another cylinder of a smaller size.

Comment: The F9 menu is specifically to adjust the last operation.  If you just opened a file there is no previous operation to adjust.

Comment: Hello ttom.  You need to apply scale to the object with ctrl + a

Comment: Allen, not sure what happened.  When open today the thickness is 1" ... which is also incorrect.  In Object mode, ctrl+a displays the Apply menu.  Now what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with your scenario b) and make a hollow cylinder.

[image]

Instead of a *Solidify* operation from *Edit Mode*, use a *Solidify Modifier*.

This will add a procedural effect that you can change on the fly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See updated comments in initial post.

Answer (score 4):

1. Begin with a cylinder primitive with no fill with <kbd>⇧
   Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *>mesh>cylinder* (change the cap fill
   type to nothing with redo panel by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> and
   choosing nothing instead of Ngon)
2. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into *edit mode* , press A to select the
   object if not already selected.
3. Use the *edit mode*> [*solidify* operator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/solidify_faces.html#solidify-faces) with <kbd>⌃
   Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>S</kbd> or
   *face>solidify faces* and adjust thickness via <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to create a hollow cylinder.  I see the "Add cylinder" menu appear on your video clip, but do not know how to make that appear.n

Comment: @ttom see my edit, maybe that's a bit more clear.

Comment: I have clarified my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the right one for you, but..

- Select top and bottom faces of a cylinder
- <kbd>I</kbd> inset them
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Edge Menu > 'Bridge Edge Loops'

[image]

Comment: I'm starting over.   I have a cylinder.  I select Edit Mode.  How do select the top and bottom face?

Comment: @ttom I don't think it's the best tutorial out there but you should definitely follow the first few episodes of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4 it would save you and us a lot of headaches since you're asking for really trivial things

Comment: Or... https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6 to get you started.

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: Why don't you create a cilinder, remove the top and bottom, go to Modifiers, choose Solidify, adjust to your liking and be done?

Comment: Not sure how to do that?  See the comments I've added.