# Creating new face between selected vertices not working

Tags: vertices, faces, error

I'm trying to fill the space between an outer an inner circle with faces. When I select the vertices I want to use to make the face it doesn't work. This is the tutorial I'm following for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzA5fOIq8Qw

I'm at the part for the screw. I've done exactly what they've done in the video but it always does the same wrong thing for me. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, please let me know. I'll include a picture of what it does for me. If you were wondering, I selected the vertices on the hexagon closest to the vertices I selected on the outer circle. Blender changes the ones I selected when I try to make the face.

[image: picture from my blender]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles/46351#46351

Comment: I don't think this will work in my situation, since my circles have different numbers of vertices. In the video I'm following along with, the person just selected all the vertices that I selected and pressed F, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: delete that edge in between ( press x -> delete edge) then try again

Comment: I just wish that people would learn how to add timestamps to their video links (it's not really that hard). Since I really don't feel like watching 25 minutes to search for "the screw part", I just recommend deleting just the faces of the inner mesh, then subdividing it until it has the same amount of vertices than the outer circle.

Comment: I've never posted something in stack exchange before. How do you add a timestamp to a video link?