# Trying to connect inside and outside of cylinder

Tags: mesh

I am trying to connect the outside of a cylinder with the inside with edges so I can subdivide it to make a vertex group of the outside only but at the moment I have no edges so when I select the outside vertex's it selects both the outside and inside.

Comment: Not sure what you're needing. My guess is that you want the cylinder to have thickness so that there is an outer shell as well as a distinct interior made up of a whole different set of faces (and hence, different vertices). If so, this is easy to do. You simply select the cylinder and then create a Solidify modifier. After dialing in the desired thickness, apply it. Now, in Edit Mode, you can opt to select the geometry on the outside without necessarily selecting the geometry on the inside. Then you can create a vertex group for only the vertices that are on the outside.

Comment: Unclear on what you want, do you want to [connect two rings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46351/92768)?

Comment: Sorry for being stupid but new to blender, when you say select the geometry on outside how do I do this, when I select the outer vertices it selects in inner ones as well. I am selecting them by making the cylinder vertical then clicking RMB and drawing a square round cylinder, plessing shift to move it and select the rest