# Can someone explain how to cut a circle out of this circle?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have this circle:
[image]

And i'm trying to cut another circle out of the center of it, roughly in a shape like this:
[image]

I've looked all over the internet, but I couldn't find anything. The only tutorial I could find about this was made in 2013, so it was a much earlier version of Blender that I couldn't follow along with. I started using Blender yesterday. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles/46351#46351

Comment: you can inset your selection (i), scale on the X axis to make the inner circle oval, then select the oval face and press X > Delete Only Face

Comment: @moonboots Got it! Thanks you so much!

Comment: didnt you try to select the top side vertices of the cylinder while in edit mode then do copy and then scale it to the size you want using the S Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the object that will be the "hole" in the 2nd object,
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + select the target object.
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode
4. <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to go to top view (the cut will be projected so the view is important).
5. Enter edit mode with both selected, go to mesh, knife project.
6. Then just remove the resulting face.

[image]