# What is the quickest way to fill the gap between two circumferences instead of filling both circumferences

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I have this shape:
[image]

I want to fill in the two inner circles vertically instead of horizontally to make this shape:
[image]

What is the quickest way to do this?

If I use F to fill, it will fill the circels horizontally and it looks like a coin instead of a ring. Grid fill didn't work either.
Currently I have to select the edges of each small segment individually and fill those gaps, but it is quite time consuming to do that for every segment.

Comment: Found the answer here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46342/104051 I didn't know bridge edge loops was a feature

Comment: Or a circle. Inset in Edit mode, select all and extrude on Z axis. Then SHIFT-N to reset the normals.

Comment: I left out the extruding in those instructions: Add a circle, then in Edit mode Select All, E S then A to select all again then E Z.

Comment: @john sorry your answer was correct, I  just misread @Cathal`s question, my mistake forgive me :)

Comment: No problem but I missed a couple of things out anyway so posted it again.