# Fill only outer ring of `6` on face

Tags: faces, tools

I have a bunch of meshes everywhere with `6/9`.

[image]

When I select the mesh and press `f` to fill, I fill the whole `6`. If I select the inner face then delete, it merges the two faces together. If I bridge edge loops, as marked in a similar question here: [Is there a way to fill the area between two circles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles)

I get something funky:

[image]

**Please reopen as this is not a duplicate of the posted question now.**

How do I only fill the outer ring of a `6`.

Bonus points if I can do that quickly for all selected 6's.

Comment: Use `ALT-f` to fill as you need

Comment: And after `Alt+F` maybe use `X` > _Limited Dissolve_ and adjust the _Angle_ in the operator settings to something low if you don't want too many vertices getting dissolved.